# SQL query to get all the heading names under a specific schema name

Tags: sql, db2, database-schema

SQL query to headings from 'Table' under a specific schema name.

```
Schema_name
      - Table

      - View
```

`SELECT TABNAME FROM syscat.tables where tabschema = 'SCHEMA-NAME'`

Above sql prints out all the tables names in both 'Table' and 'View' but I just want the table names under 'Table'

Comment: Removed [tag:mysql] tag, because MySQL does not have `syscat`. The question is also tagged [tag:db2] and DB2 does have [syscat.tables](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=views-syscattables).

Comment: syscat.tables has other columns. Look for type which should be T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an additional filter

```
   WHERE TYPE = 'T'
```

this will limit your result to tables.

More details can be found [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=views-syscattables)